# Scale Image from current size and not from original size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scale

Basically i am trying to scale an img with an id="room"  according to a parameter wich will be +1 or -1   (and its a constant that i want to scale +-10%)

this is how i am trying

```
function scalar(scaleP100){ /* scaleP100 is +1 or -1 (no  other posible value)*/
                    var addX = $('#room').width()*10*scaleP100/100;
                    var addY = $('#room').height()*10*scaleP100/100;
                    var newW = $('#room').width()+ addX;
                    var newH = $('#room').height()  + addY;
                    $('img#room').css({'width':newW,'height':newH});
                    console.log(newW +','+ newH+':'+$('img#room').length);
                    return false;
}
```

This is inside a mouswheel detection,

So it has two stages: +10% from original size, and -10% **from original** size. I just don't know why **it doesn't scale acording the current size** (instead of the original size)

what am i doing wrong?

**If you want to see** what i probably didn't explain well, please check http://toniweb.us/m/3d/adam.html (but mousewheel outside the image only)

Thanks

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand your question ? Your demo works fine in my browser.

Comment: What are you asking? It does scale according to the current size... Are you wondering why there are rounding errors?

Comment: @mdi it only resizes once (bigger or smaller) , i want it to resize every mousewheel up or down (i want infinite sizes, no only 3) and remember the last size to re-scale (it seems to be calculating from the original size the whole time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two elements with same id:
<div id="room"> and <img id="room">
This should work, but I suggest you to make your html cleaner..

```
function scalar(scaleP100){ /* scaleP100 is +1 or -1 (no  other posible value)*/
    var addX = $('img#room').width()*10*scaleP100/100;
    var addY = $('img#room').height()*10*scaleP100/100;
    var newW = $('img#room').width()+ addX;
    var newH = $('img#room').height()  + addY;
    $('img#room').css({'width':newW,'height':newH});
    console.log(newW +','+ newH+':'+$('img#room').length);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: that's weird! the spining plugin is adding the same image's id to the parent, didn't realise that, thanks!!!